# How to search a word in a docx file with powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have to examine all of .docx files in a folder and i have to display the name of files which is contain that word I added as param. How can I do it in powershell?

Comment: [You either need to convert it to text first](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28481/63662) or use the [Word Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386277.aspx). If you have a working solution, do post it as I could use it myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try someting like this:

```
#Instance of word
$Word=NEW-Object –comobject Word.Application
$Word.visible = $False

#take list of .docx
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -file -Filter "*.docx" | %{

$Filename=$_.FullName

#open file and take content of word file
$Document=$Word.documents.open($Filename, $false, $true)
$range = $document.content

#if content have your word, print path of word file
If($range.Text -like "*tot*"){
    $Filename
}

$word.Documents.Close($false)

}
```

Comment: Thanks. How to put these command lines together and executed line by line?